# Enumerating a sequence and if-then-else

Tags: loops, prolog

To emulate a simple loop like that:

```
start = something; 
incr = something_else;
end = yet_something_else; /* all three are numerical values, int or float */
while (start <= end) {
    /* do something for its side effect, for example: */
    printf("%d %d\n", start, start*start);
    start += incr;
}
```

I could write either:

```
loop1(Start, End, _Incr) :-
    Start > End, !. % yes, the cut is necessary!
loop1(Start, End, Incr) :-
    Start =< End,
    /* do something for its side effect, for example */
    format('~d ~d~n', [Start, Start*Start]),
    Next is Start + Incr,
    loop1(Next, End, Incr).
```

or:

```
loop2(Start, End, Incr) :-
    (   Start =< End
    ->  format('~d ~d~n, [Start, Start*Start]),
        Next is Start + Incr,
        loop2(Next, End, Incr)
    ;   true
    ).
```

`loop/3` must (and always will be) called with all arguments instantiated to numbers.

I should be using the second version, right? The only reason there is a doubt is that the if-then-else construct is pretty much absent from introductory Prolog material, and I can't figure out why ([Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online), for example, otherwise a good introductory material, doesn't even mention it!). At the same time there are cuts haphazardly flying every each way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my preferred way, that resembles structured programming, is between/3 coupled with forall/2.

```
?- forall(between(1,3,N), writeln(N)).
```

here is an 'applicative' example, from ICLP2013 contest:

```
icecream(N) :-
    loop(N, top(N)),
    left, loop(N+1, center), nl,
    loop(N+1, bottom(N)).

:- meta_predicate loop(+, 1).

loop(XH, PR) :-
    H is XH,
    forall(between(1, H, I), call(PR, I)).

top(N, I) :-
    left, spc(N-I+1), pop,
    (   I > 1
    ->  pop,
        spc(2*(I-2)),
        pcl
    ;   true
    ),
    pcl, nl.

bottom(N, I) :-
    left, spc(I-1), put(\), spc(2*(N-I+1)), put(/), nl.

center(_) :- put(/), put(\).

left :- spc(4).
pop :- put(0'().
pcl :- put(0')).
spc(Ex) :- V is Ex, forall(between(1, V, _), put(0' )).
```

yields

```
2 ?- [icecream].
% icecream compiled 0.00 sec, 10 clauses
true.

3 ?- icecream(5).
         ()
        (())
       ((  ))
      ((    ))
     ((      ))
    /\/\/\/\/\/\
    \          /
     \        /
      \      /
       \    /
        \  /
         \/
true.
```

Comment: As much as I like forall/2, it forces me to write my own between/4 predicate if I want to have a step not 1 and non-integers. Or do some arithmetic with the results of between (which breaks the logic). Do you see the problem?

Comment: Of course, but I would extend (for instance) loop/2 to loop/3. Then you can forget about details and build declarative programs (don't you like my fresh icecream ? :) the key is 'higher order' programming...

Comment: Sergei above you actually provided a generalized version of between/3 (in his solution it is called loop/4). With it, forall is maybe the exact solution I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they don't mention it. All practical programmers use it.

But we can avoid using of cut/if-then-else if rewrite your code with a failure-driven loop.

```
loop(From, To, Incr, Val) :- 
  From =< To,
  ( Val = From
  ; Next is From + Incr,
    loop(Next, To, Incr, Val)
  ).

print_squares(Start, End, Incr) :-
  loop(Start, End, Incr, Val),
  Square is Val * Val,
  format('~d ~d~n', [Val, Square]),
  fail
  ; 
  true.
```

In a case Incr = 1 you can use between/3 from the standard library:

```
print_squares(Start, End) :-
  between(Start, End, Val),
  Square is Val * Val,
  format('~d ~d~n', [Val, Square]),
  fail
  ; 
  true.
```

If you know Russian or can translate it I can recommend my book http://sourceforge.net/projects/uranium-test/files/prolog/speed_prolog.pdf/download as an introductory matherial for Prolog.

Comment: The example in the beginning was misleading and I changed it. Incr is not necessarily 1, and Start and End need not be integers (so between/3 and plus/3 are out of the question). But apart from that, I am not sure that your first solution is more obvious/readable than the (if -> then ; else) loop.
P.S. Thank you for the book, I understand enough Russian to read it, I will definitely have a look at it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know Russian. Do you think the output of Goggle translator is worth to read ? Anyway, I'll try and report...

Comment: @Boris Thank you for pointing me to the error. I've changed the first example to a more generic form. Now it works even with rationals. For arbitrary sequences you need slightly different concept. And of course, your solution is more readable, but it is hard to use as a generic solution with different "side effects" (because sequence generation and action are mixed).

Comment: Well, the Google Docs output seems fairly readable - just some glitch ( some unknown words, some wrong rendering - maybe just problems specific to my javascript env - firefox ). Will need manual editing from a competent reader...

Comment: @CapelliC It is my miss, I had no time yet to translate the book but I plan. If you will have questions don't hesitate to write me.

Comment: loop/4, as it stands, is an "extended" version of between, which is nice. It could be used instead of between/3 in @CapelliC's answer below.

Comment: @SergeiLodyagin: I didn't actually *read* your paper (yet), but if you like, I could publish the translation amended (with my guesses), of course with the right attribution to you as author. Then you could grab/correct any point from my blog. What do you think ?

Comment: @CapelliC You may publish it but please warn that it is a google-translated thing. I hope I will be able make/propose corrections. One day I will place the book on my own site (may be with additional chapters) and I will ask you to place the link (in a "follow" mode) on your page. If you can accept my requirements you may publish it (it will also motivate me to translate it better way than google do).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to enumerate a sequence of (float) numbers:

```
sequence(First, Step, Last, R) :-
    D is Last - First,
    sign(Step) =:= sign(D),
    N is floor(D / Step),
    between(0, N, X),
    R is First + X * Step.
```

One of the virtues of this solution is that it does not accumulate a floating point error like `Next is This + Step`.